# Do evaporating black holes emit gravitons?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-gravity, hawking-radiation

Do evaporating black holes emit gravitons? I know that hawking radiation consists of photons, and that for very small black holes it can also consists of sun atomic particles, but what about gravitons? Those are supposedly massless particles, can an astrophysical black hole emit those?

Comment: You don't need a black hole for gravitons. Every mass emits and absorbs gravitons, similar to an electric charge emitting/absorbings photons.